# Zend Framework 2 ZendOAuth with Google

Tags: php, oauth, zend-framework2, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I'm semi-familiar with the ZendFramework/ZendOAuth library found here https://github.com/zendframework/ZendOAuth

I am able to use it no problem with Twitter, but I can't figure out how to get it to work with Google OAuth 2.0.  The code I'm trying to use is as follows:

```
$config = array(
        'callbackUrl' => 'https://www.example.com/callback',
        'siteUrl' => 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2',
        'userAuthorizationUrl' => 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth',
        'requestTokenUrl' => 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
        'consumerKey' => 'MY-CONSUMER-KEY-HERE',
        'consumerSecret' => 'MY-SECRET-KEY-HERE',
        'version' => '2.0',
    );

    $scopes = array(
        'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo'
    );

    $consumer = new Consumer($config);
    $token = $consumer->getRequestToken(array('scope' => implode('', $scopes), 'response_type' => 'code', 'redirect_uri' => 'https://www.example.com/callback'));
    $consumer->redirect();
```

According to the documentation for ZendOAuth, an array in the getRequestToken function gets treated as custom OAuth parameters.  However, when I run this code I get redirected to a Google page that says:

**Required parameter is missing: response_type**

The URL in the browser shows the following:

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?oauth_token=&oauth_callback=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fcallback

I've tried throwing debug statements around in the ZendOAuth library, but I can't seem to be able to find the problem.

If anyone has a solution to this, it would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the ZendOAuth package only supports OAuth 1, so for OAuth 2 you'll need to find a different library. I've used https://github.com/php-loep/oauth2-client with ZF2 applications so you could start there.

Comment: Hi Tim, I went back to searching and couldn't find what version ZendOAuth supported so I'm going to say you're probably right that ZendOAuth 2.* doesn't support OAuth2.  A question for you though.  How do all these libraries initiate a redirect when using an Http Client?  Whenever I try to use an Http Client, instead of ZF2 redirecting me to the Google page, it embeds it in my page (url doesn't change) which is not correct.  I can't seem to figure out how all these libraries make the direct happen with the Http Client.  Any ideas?

Comment: The libraries will generally use the PHP `header()` function to do the redirect. In the code example in your question, this happens when you call `$consumer->redirect()`, see https://github.com/zendframework/ZendOAuth/blob/master/library/ZendOAuth/Consumer.php#L134

Comment: Thanks, I got it now and decided to make my own library.  I'm sure there are others with my troubles. http://code.nraboy.com/zfgoogle